# problems with resolv.conf and dnsmasq

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, dhcp

i'm trying to configure two interface, eth0 is into a net with internet and is working, and in eth1 i'm trying to configure a local net, connect to another computer (host b) through a crossed ethernet (i don't want this local net have internet), this is what i have in /etc/network/interface:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.1.253
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.1.154
      dns-nameservers 10.10.0.10

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 192.168.100.1
      netmask 255.255.255.0
```

i want to use  dnsmasq to provides network infrastructure through eth1 to host b in a local network, this is what i have in dnsmasq.conf:

```
no-resolv
dhcp-host=02:00:01:02:02:08,192,168,100,2
dhcp-option=17,192.168.100.1:/srv/hostb_boot/etch
dhcp-boot=uImage
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/srv/hostb_boot/boot
dhcp-authoritative
interface=eth1
bind-interface
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

when i make /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart it doesn't work.
i had made sudo service network-manager stop (and with networkmanger running  neither work) but not sure if the resolvconf program, or DHCP clients are maybe overwriting something .
this is what i have in /etc/resolvconf/interface-order:

```
#interface-order(5)
eth*
lo.dnsmasq
lo.inet*
lo.pdnsd
lo.!(pdns|pdns-recursor)
lo
tun*
tap*
hso*
em+([0-9])?(_+([0-9]))*
p+([0-9])p+([0-9])?(_+([0-9]))*
ath*
```

and in dhclient.conf:

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-route code 121 =array of unsigned integer 8;
send host-name"<hostname>"
request subnet-mask,broadcast-address,time-offset,routers, domain-name,doman-name-servers,domain-search,host-name,rfc3442-classless-static-route, ntp-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn,dhcp6.name-servers,dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

I'm not sure if I have to disable something so this can work or if i'm making something wrong.
also this is what i have in /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 10.10.0.10 (in red)
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

If anyone can help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You could run `/usr/sbin/dnsmasq` and see what actually goes wrong. Don't know if it is a copy paste error but you have in your dhcp-host, commas instead of dots in the ip address.

Comment: Also I'm not quite understanding what you are trying to achieve? You want to use dnsmasq as a dhcp service without the dns feature? Just use the `port=0` functionality then the DNS is turned off. Aswell using the tftpserver that is implemented in it?